# direct printing from a phonegap tablet app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, printing, google-cloud-print

i'm writing a phonegap app for android tablets:

basically i have two storage departments (say tyres and brakes).
people in both departments have a tablet app.
the app is a to-do-list app synced with a db; people should print selected items on a paper receipt ( so  that different people can print a list and collect items in the storage department without having to carry the tablet with themselves).

can't figure out a way to print; truth is that i'm not very up-to-date with printers technologies.
here what i tried and what i suppose:

-i tried some phonegap plugins that make use of google cloud print, they work but everytime a confirmation page (print preview) appears, leaving the app screen.

-on server side, i could do it with php, but it sounds silly (apparently) to do network printing via php, sending the list from tablet to server via json and then to the printer of the right department

-i have no experience with bluetooth or wifi printers (sure there are, but are there some with something like an API? something like the out-of-stock mprinter?)

Any smarter way?

Comment: ps. i'm not sure i'll have a chance to install on kitkat devices (so i was not considering android printing framework)

Comment: check this one https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-printer/tree/network-printer

Comment: i already used it (the branch for Android <= 4.3) but when printing it shows a print preview page)